# Strange Behavior of CollectionView WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collectionview

I've faced a really strange behavior while using CollectionViews and wonder if somebody can explain me that behavior.

I've got an ObservableCollection, lets call it _sourcelist. Then I create several CollectionViews of _sourcelist, in that way:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = _sourcelist };
ICollectionView list = cvs.View;
```

These CollectionViews are each used with a different filter and one CollectionView with no filter (so representing the original source). In my Application I have a TabControl where every TabItem contains a ListBox with one of these CollectionViews as ItemsSource. When I know delete an item from the sourcelist, the ListBox with the CollectionView with no filter gets updated, but the other ListBoxes that contains filtered CollectionViews and contain the deleted item don't get updated. So the deleted item remains in that ListBoxes.

Now, the strange behavior is following:
When I add the following code after code written above:

```
list.CollectionChanged += (o,e) => { };
```

Then the other ListBoxes get updated, too.
Why that? I mean, I just registered an event handler for the CollectionChanged event, which does nothing!

---

So, here is my Code Sample. I know it is a big amount of code, but it is ready to run and reproduces the strange behavior.

When you run the code and try to delete an item in the "All" List, then the corresponding item in the filtered "Under 30" or "Over 30" list will not be deleted. Now uncomment the commented line in the ListViewModel (it is just a registration of an empty Eventhandler), then the corresponding items in the filtered lists will be deleted.

If you have any questions, then please ask! :-)

Thank you for your interest in solving the problem. :-)

P.S.: The RelayCommand is from the assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ListViewModel}">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PersonViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="DeleteButton" Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
        <TabControl Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}" Padding="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel mvm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mvm = new MainViewModel(CreateRepo());
        this.DataContext = mvm;
    }

    private Repository CreateRepo()
    {
        Repository repo = new Repository();

        for (int i = 20; i < 45; i++) 
        {
            Person p = new Person() { Name = "Person" + i, Age = i };
            repo.Add(p);
        }

        return repo;
    }
}
```

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly List<Person> _list;

    public event EventHandler<RepositoryChangedEventArgs> Added;

    public event EventHandler<RepositoryChangedEventArgs> Removed;

    public Repository()
    {
        this._list = new List<Person>();
    }

    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
        }

        if (!this._list.Contains(person))
        {
            this._list.Add(person);

            if (this.Added != null)
            {
                this.Added(this, new RepositoryChangedEventArgs(person));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
        }

        if (this._list.Contains(person))
        {
            this._list.Remove(person);

            if (this.Removed != null)
            {
                this.Removed(this, new RepositoryChangedEventArgs(person));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Person> Get()
    {
        return new List<Person>(this._list);
    }
}

public class RepositoryChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Person Entity { get; set; }

    public RepositoryChangedEventArgs(Person entity)
    {
        this.Entity = entity;
    }
}
```

PersonViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _person;

    private Repository _repository;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._person.Name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._person.Name != value)
            {
                this._person.Name = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return this._person.Age;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._person.Age != value)
            {
                this._person.Age = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person person, Repository repository)
    {
        this._person = person;
        this._repository = repository;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        this._repository.Remove(this._person);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

ListViewModel:

```
public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IEnumerable _sourceList;

    private ICollectionView _list;

    private PersonViewModel _selected;

    private string _name;

    public ICollectionView List
    {
        get
        {
            return this._list;
        }
    }

    public PersonViewModel Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selected;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._selected != value)
            {
                this._selected = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._name != value)
            {
                this._name = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public ListViewModel(string name, IEnumerable list)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this._sourceList = list;
        CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = list };
        this._list = cvs.View;

        // cvs.View.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => { }; // uncomment this line to let it work
    }

    public ListViewModel(String name, IEnumerable list, Predicate<object> filter)
        : this(name, list)
    {
        this._list.Filter = filter;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> _sourceList;

    protected ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> _lists;

    protected Repository _repository;

    protected Dictionary<Person, PersonViewModel> _dictionary;

    private RelayCommand _deleteCommand;

    private ListViewModel _selected;

    public ListViewModel Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selected;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._selected != value)
            {
                this._selected = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._deleteCommand == null)
            {
                this._deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecutedDelete, this.CanExecuteDelete);
            }

            return this._deleteCommand;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ListViewModel> Lists
    {
        get
        {
            return this._lists;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel(Repository repository)
    {
        this._sourceList = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
        this._lists = new ObservableCollection<ListViewModel>();
        this._dictionary = new Dictionary<Person, PersonViewModel>();
        this._repository = repository;
        this._repository.Added += this.OnAdded;
        this._repository.Removed += this.OnRemoved;

        this.CreateSourceList(repository);
        this.CreateLists();

        if (this._lists.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Selected = this._lists[0];
        }
    }

    protected void CreateSourceList(Repository repository)
    {
        foreach (Person person in repository.Get())
        {
            PersonViewModel pvm = new PersonViewModel(person, repository);
            this._dictionary.Add(person, pvm);
            this._sourceList.Add(pvm);
        }
    }

    protected void CreateLists()
    {
        this._lists.Add(new ListViewModel("All", this._sourceList));
        this._lists.Add(new ListViewModel("Under 30", this._sourceList,
            delegate(object o)
            {
                PersonViewModel pvm = o as PersonViewModel;

                return (pvm != null && pvm.Age < 30);
            }));
        this._lists.Add(new ListViewModel("Over 30", this._sourceList,
            delegate(object o)
            {
                PersonViewModel pvm = o as PersonViewModel;

                return (pvm != null && pvm.Age > 30);
            }));
    }

    protected void Remove(Person person)
    {
        PersonViewModel pvm = this._dictionary[person];
        this._dictionary.Remove(person);
        this._sourceList.Remove(pvm);
    }

    protected void OnAdded(object sender, RepositoryChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Person addedPerson = args.Entity;

        if (addedPerson != null)
        {
            PersonViewModel pvm = new PersonViewModel(addedPerson, this._repository);
            this._dictionary.Add(addedPerson, pvm);
            this._sourceList.Add(pvm);
        }
    }

    protected void OnRemoved(object sender, RepositoryChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Person removedPerson = args.Entity;

        if (removedPerson != null)
        {
            this.Remove(removedPerson);
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteDelete(object o)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecutedDelete(object o)
    {
        PersonViewModel pvm = null;

        if (this.Selected != null && (pvm = this.Selected.Selected) != null)
        {
            pvm.Delete();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are the `ListBoxes` 'updated'. Are you doing anything in the event handler or is it empty as above?

Comment: Yes that is the point. The event handler is empty as above. I don't update them explicitly, because I thought they would do it automatically, because the source is an ObservableCollection. And the one CollectionView without filter, updates indeed automatically, but the others not.

And the weird thing is that when I add only this line of code with the empty event handler, then the other lists are updating, too. And I wonder why?

Comment: I think I am missing something here. You are going to have to post some more code including the XAML and the properties you are binding to. If you are merely saying that the empty event handler is causing the UI to spontaneously update, then yes, that is strange, but the cause is not at all clear from the information you have posted...

Comment: Are you removing items like this: _sourceList.Remove(..)???

Comment: @TobyNick - Can you post small sample replicating an issue? I tried it in small app and it works fine for me.

Comment: I will try to post some code this evening. Then I have time. I've already tried to create a small sample to reproduce the behavior but then it worked fine. I think I have to shorten my project where it happens, such that it contains only the necessary elements but still letting the behavior happen.

Comment: I've posted a ready-to-run example down below.

Comment: I've found another solution to let it work correctly.
At the moment I store the ICollectionView (new CollectionViewSource { Source=... }.View) in a separate variable _list and bind this variable to the ItemsSource of the ListBox. Then the strange behavior happens. But when I store the CollectionViewSource in a Property CVS and bind the Property with {Binding Path=CVS.View} to the ItemsSource of the ListBox then it works fine.

Comment: Do you set `IsLiveFilteringRequested = true`?